# web start creating xml with out of date meta description

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am new to java Web Start and trying to set up a jnlp download on my server.

The Web start seems to initiate ok, butit gives the following error:

```
WARNING: <meta> tag is not closed correctly Exception parsing xml at line 3
```

Line 3 just contains the meta descriptions. Originally I used some characters the xml parse might object to, these were "-" and "(" ")". Suspecting that these characters might not be valid in a meta description, I removed them from the meta on my web page and in the jnlp script.

However, when I try to run Web start, it still has line 3 as:

```
<head><title>xxxxxx</title><meta name="author" content="xxxxx"><meta name="keywords" content="xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx"><meta name="description" content="xxxx (xxx) xxxxx, xxxx, 2-12 players."></head>
```

In other words it is not showing my updated meta info. Where is it getting this old version from, and how can I update it?

And most importantly, are the characters "- ( ) ," causing my problem anyway?

Here is a link to my site. Be aware it's not quite ready to go live yet!
[fantasyhexwars.com/getting_started.html](http://fantasyhexwars.com/getting_started.html)

Comment: Why does webstart try to parse what looks like an HTML file, rather than the JNLP file? Isn't there something misconfigured here?

Comment: Quite possibly something is configured wrong! I've updated my question with a link so you can see how it fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quite possibly something is configured wrong!

It seems so.

http://fantasyhexwars.com/include/launch.jnlp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Fantasy Hex Wars</title><meta name="author" content="Mark Keen"><meta name="keywords" content="strategy fantasy hex wars multiplayer war game turn based"><meta name="description" content="An online, turn-based, strategy game for up to 12 players."><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://91.223.16.102/httpdocs/favicon.ico"></head>
<frameset rows="100%,*">
<frame title="http://91.223.16.102/include/launch.jnlp" src="http://91.223.16.102/include/launch.jnlp" name="mainframe" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="auto">
<frame title="empty frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize">
<noframes>Sorry, you don"t appear to have frame support.
Go here instead - <a href="http://91.223.16.102/include/launch.jnlp">Fantasy Hex Wars</a></noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

http://91.223.16.102/include/launch.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://fantasyhexwars.com/httpdocs/include" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Fantasy Hex Wars</title>
        <vendor>Fysh Games</vendor>
        <homepage href="fantasyhexwars.com"/>
        <description>A turn-based, online, multiplayer strategy game.</description>
        <description kind="short">Fantasy Hex Wars</description>

    </information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
<j2se version="1.5+"/>
<jar href="FantasyHexWar.jar" main="true"/>


    <jar href="lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="fantasyhexwar.FantasyHexWarApp">

    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: hmmm, thanks, that certainly is intriguing... sorry it won't let me give you a +1.